# Slim 3 route parameter

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

I encountered strange square bracket in Slim-Skeleton routes.php

```
$app->get('/[{name}]', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    // Sample log message
    $this->logger->info("Slim-Skeleton '/' route");

    // Render index view
    return $this->renderer->render($response, 'index.phtml', $args);
});
```

Why use square bracket? I tried to look at the documentation but it gives me nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the docs](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html):

> #### Optional segments
>
> To make a section optional, simply wrap in square brackets

So the route `$app->get('/[{name}]'` matches any URL string, including none `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets mean that route parameter is optional.

> Furthermore parts of the route enclosed in [...] are considered optional, so that /foo[bar] will match both /foo and /foobar. Optional parts are only supported in a trailing position, not in the middle of a route. - [nikic/FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute)

Slim is built on top of FastRoute. See [**defining routes**](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute#defining-routes) to learn more about the FastRoute routing syntax.